# Add a button to View

Tags: button, view, android

I'm drawing a graph then add some button/label/textbox for input data. But the button on main layout is't show up. how to add button to a View (Because i draw graph using canvas on a View)

here is draw canvas class

```
public class DrawCross extends View {
    Paint   paint   = new Paint();

    public DrawCross(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Button btn = new Button(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawLine(250, 450, 250, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(245, 25, 250, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(250, 20, 255, 25, paint);

        canvas.drawLine(20, 300, 400, 300, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(395, 295, 400, 300, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(400, 300, 395, 305, paint); 
    }
}
```

this is main class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawCross   drawView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        drawView = new DrawCross(this);
        setContentView(drawView);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fixed:

DrawCross class:

```
public class DrawCross extends View {
    Paint   paint   = new Paint();

    public DrawCross(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawLine(250, 450, 250, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(245, 25, 250, 20, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(250, 20, 255, 25, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(20, 300, 400, 300, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(395, 295, 400, 300, paint);
        canvas.drawLine(400, 300, 395, 305, paint);
    }
}
```

main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawCross   drawView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="a" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="draw" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <com.example.khibong.DrawCross
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.khibong"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.khibong.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and the logcat:

```
05-12 12:56:16.831: E/Trace(1715): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
05-12 12:56:16.841: D/AndroidRuntime(1715): Shutting down VM
05-12 12:56:16.841: W/dalvikvm(1715): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3e28288)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.khibong/com.example.khibong.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.example.khibong.DrawCross
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class com.example.khibong.DrawCross
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at com.example.khibong.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     ... 11 more
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)
05-12 12:56:16.841: E/AndroidRuntime(1715):     ... 22 more
```

[image]

Comment: @Triode I've tried extends RelativeLayout for DrawCross class but onDraw of RelativeLayout doesn't like onDraw of View. When i changed to RelativeLayout, every thing i draw disappear. how to fix it?

Comment: @Triode I've add super.onDraw but the draw still isn't show up. I've udpate my fixed code on post. Is there anything wrong ??

Comment: what you want ti achieve ? can you post the final result image what you want to get by doing this ?

Comment: @Triode i need to draw lines, and button at same time. something like picture i've updated above

Comment: See the edited answer. You can add more options inside the xml files itself.

Comment: @Triode tks for still support newbie like me :D. I've tried, but the error caused by: 
    <com.example.khibong.DrawCross
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
i've update code and logcat above, can you help me

Comment: put android:weight="5" in the outermost LinearLayout, in the inner LinearLayout put android:layout_weight="1" and android:layout_height="0dp" and finally in DrawCross android:layout_height="0dp" and android:layout_weight="4"

Comment: your package name is not correct

Comment: @Triode I think it's correct http://i1335.photobucket.com/albums/w672/dolphin19303/packet_zpsb07dcc48.png. 
Is there anything must declare on manifest?.

Comment: @HoanNguyen I've tried, It doesn't solve problem.

Comment: @Triode i think android:name=".MainActivity" is a short form of android:name="com.example.khibong.MainActivity" but it doesn't. 
I've learn something new. thanks you so much :D. 
everything's working now

Comment: I needed the same answer where I'm doing the drawing on the Activity's view and I needed to be able to add widgets to the View via layout also and your question got me to this answer which worked for me. Great question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try your earlier DrawCross and it does what you want but it is a little bit ugly. You have to set the baseline to make it look nice

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
DrawCross   drawView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DrawCross drawCross = new DrawCross(this);
    LinearLayout layout1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawcross);
    layout1.addView(drawCross);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="10"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="label1" />

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textview1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Draw" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="label2" />

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="label3" />

        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/drawcross"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great, clear answer.  Really appreciate it.  It was difficult to even search for this answer -- a hybrid view with programmatically drawn elements and layout elements and you explained the answer very succinctly and clearly.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="a" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="draw" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <yourPacakageName.DrawCross
        android:id="@+id/myView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Create a lay out like this and set this as content for your Activity. Also

```
public class DrawCross extends View
```

Use View to extend your `DrawCross`. The yourPacakageName should be exactly the package name of your `DrawCross`.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.khibong.MainActivity"
```

change this to

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
```