# How to link a Layout in XML with a View Class?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to do a photo editor app for my own learning and I am struggling to incorporate a View subclass in an XML file to better design the process.

Here is the XML code :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:context=".home">


       <com.example.digitaldesign.createObjectLayout
           android:id="@+id/CreateObj"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the View Class:

```
    package com.example.digitaldesign;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Canvas;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.view.View;


    public class createObjectLayout extends View {

        Bitmap tshirt;

        public createObjectLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
            setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wall);
            tshirt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.tshirt);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Rect trect = new Rect();
            trect.set(50,50,1050,1350 );
            canvas.drawBitmap(tshirt,null,trect,null);
        }
    }
```

And here is the Activity:

````
 ```package com.example.digitaldesign;

    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;

    public class createObject extends AppCompatActivity {

        createObjectLayout CreateObj;
        Button btn;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            CreateObj = new createObjectLayout(this);

            LinearLayout layout1 =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.CreateObj);
            layout1.addView(CreateObj);

            setContentView(R.layout.createobjectlyt);



        }
    }
````

And the error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary 
XML file line #10: Error inflating class 
com.example.digitaldesign.createObjectLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: 
Error inflating class com.example.digitaldesign.createObjectLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class 
android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
```

I tried to do everything like here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504243/add-a-button-to-view#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504243/add-a-button-to-view#_=_)  , but i still get the error. Can you please tell me what am i doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: To be able to be inflated from layout XML, your custom `View` class must have a two-parameter constructor that takes a `Context` and an `AttributeSet`; e.g., `public createObjectLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {`, `super(context, attrs);`, `...`. That's what `NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]` is saying.

Comment: I would also point out that the given setup is creating two `createObjectLayout`s; one from the layout, and one in code, though you'd be discarding that one, anyway. If you don't really mean to be creating two like that, then you maybe want to remove that code section, between `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, i did the modifications in the ```createObjectLayout``` View Class but what should I pass as the second parameter here: ```CreateObj = new createObjectLayout(this,);```  ?

Comment: Ok, I removed it from the code and it gives me this error: ```Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.digitaldesign.createObjectLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout```

Comment: Update: After deleting also the layout from the code, not just the ```createObjectLayout```, it works, thank you

Comment: Yeah, I meant remove everything between `super.onCreate()` and `setContentView()`. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must get an error as you try to inflate widgets from XML layout before using `setContentView()`

So, modify your code to transfer `setContentView()` just after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
public class createObject extends AppCompatActivity {

    createObjectLayout CreateObj;
    Button btn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.createobjectlyt);
        CreateObj = new createObjectLayout(this);

       ...
    }
}
```

The second thing you need to include all the constructors of your custom view

```
public class createObjectLayout extends View {

    Bitmap tshirt;

    public createObjectLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        tshirt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
    }

    public createObjectLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        tshirt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
    }

    public createObjectLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        tshirt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
    }

    public createObjectLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        tshirt = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Rect trect = new Rect();
        trect.set(50, 50, 1050, 1350);
        canvas.drawBitmap(tshirt, trect, trect, new Paint());
    }
}
```

Third, you will get `ClassCastException` as you inflate your custom view as a `LinearLayout` so change it to

```
createObjectLayout myView = findViewById(R.id.CreateObj);
```

Also as your custom view is not a `ViewGroup`, then you can't add views to it. So the below statement will raise exception

```
layout1.addView(CreateObj);
```

I encourage your to have a look at [Android Custom Views](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components)

Comment: I still get an error, i'll post it if it helps

Comment: @Florentin-AlexandruIosif sure please post it

Comment: i posted only what i think is the main part because it would look ugly if i don't post it as a code, and the editing won't allow me to post all of it because it would be too much code

Comment: @Florentin-AlexandruIosif  `XML file line #10:` you've error on line 10 in the layout file; which you try to include your class `com.example.digitaldesign.createObjectLayout` in XML, please make sure that you don't have typos on the class path including packages

Comment: ```com.example.digitaldesign.createObjectLayout``` this is the line 10, and  ```createObjectLayout```  is the name of the View, so it's good, and the ```digitaldesign``` it's the name of the app

Comment: @Florentin-AlexandruIosif please check updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now it works :)

Comment: @Florentin-AlexandruIosif happy it could help.. If my answer was useful, please click the checkmark (✓) at the left to accept it. That way help others who have similar questions.